# How to get SUM of one column after ORDER BY and LIMIT?

Tags: sql, select, sum, sql-order-by

sql:

```
    SELECT instock.rating
    FROM instock
    JOIN products
    ON instock.code_id=products.code
    WHERE products.brand="Adidas"
    ORDER BY -instock.rating
    LIMIT 5;
```

for example:
return:
5
5
6
6
7

I need SUM(i.rating) after Where, Order By and Limit, returns 5+ 5+ 6+ 6+ 7.

After ORDER BY response contains about 200 rows.
My try examples:
1:

```
    SELECT SUM(instock.rating) 
    FROM instock
    JOIN products
    ON instock.code_id=products.code
    WHERE products.brand="Adidas"
    ORDER BY -instock.rating
    LIMIT 5;
```

returns, value: 3000, so, SUM all query.
2:

```
    SELECT SUM(DISTINCT instock.rating)
    FROM instock
    JOIN products
    ON instock.code_id=products.code
    WHERE products.brand="Adidas"
    ORDER BY -instock.rating
    LIMIT 5;
```

returns: 5+ 6+ 7== 19, so, SUM single i.

How get value: 5+ 5+ 6+ 6+ 7 = 29 from first sql example?

Comment: 1) tag your database 2) provide sample data and desired output

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT SUM(rate)
FROM (SELECT i.rating as rate
    FROM instock_nagornaya AS i 
    JOIN products AS p
    ON code_id=code
    WHERE p.brand="Adidas"
    ORDER BY -i.rating
    LIMIT 5);
```

May be more faster solve?